# Show message dialog

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt5.12

Is it possible to display a QML dialog when the user hits a button in a QML window?

**Example**:

When the user clicks in the menu bar on *Help -> About* the About dialog should be displayed:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

import "components"

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 1040
    height: 480


    aboutDlg: aboutDialog {}  // does not work...

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("Help")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("About")
                onTriggered: aboutDlg.open();
        }
    }
    ...
```

**components/AboutDialog.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1

MessageDialog {
    id: aboutDialog
    title: "May I have your attention please"
    text: "It's so cool that you are using Qt Quick."
    onAccepted: {
        console.log("And of course you could only agree.")
        Qt.quit()
    }
}
```

When I remove the line `boutDlg: aboutDialog {}  // does not work...` the following error is reported when clicking on the About menu item:

> qrc:/main.qml:61: ReferenceError: aboutDlg is not defined

How can I achieve this?

Comment: More info is [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-definetypes.html). Also I advice to start learning QML from [this](https://qmlbook.github.io/) pretty book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You called "aboutDialog" which is an ID in the AboutDialog.
Think of it like you add an object, like adding a Rectangle...which has its own file...and you can "instantiate" it by adding an object like so:

```
...

ApplicationWindow {

...

    AboutDialog {
        id: aboutDlg
    }

...
}
```

You can find example [HERE](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-documents-definetypes.html)

You might also optimize a bit and put the AboutDialog in a [Loader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html).

Comment: please add some explanation. code only answers are discouraged in SO